# Social Interation in laravel 5.4 using socialite pluign

Tags: php, facebook-social-plugins, laravel-5.4

I am try to Signup with facebook in laravel 5.4 application using Socialite plugin ...I configured that plugin in my page but while i redirect to facebook page from my app it shows an error.
[image]

I Think want to change subdomain but I Doknow what is exactly means???

Answer (score 0):

After authenticating, Facebook sends a secret access token back to the app that allows to access that user's data. Facebook will only redirect to URIs that have been explicitly allowed in the Facebook App settings.

Go to the "Facebook Login" tab in your app settings page on  [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) and add the  URL into the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" box. After saving the changes, the error message should disappear.

Comment: Although you need to have Valid OAuth Redirect URIs set, the message complains about the app domain not being set - so they will have to do that as well.